# New to VBA - Column deletion issue

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like what I'm trying to do is simple but am hitting snags with my macro. The current iteration works, but removes columns outside of what I have defined and I'm not sure why that's happening. a little lost, looking for a some clarity.

```
Sub ModifyWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim col As Range
    Dim unwantedHeaders As Variant
    Dim insertColumn As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    unwantedHeaders = Array("A", "C", "G", "H", "K", "L", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "W", "AA", "AB", "AG", "AH", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BF", "BG", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BP", "BQ") ' Adjust with your headers
    
        Set col = ws.Rows(1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not col Is Nothing Then
            col.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next header
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `Next header` line, but I see no loop. Are you missing code from your copy/paste? Can you please share specifically what you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: What's your expected output? Do you want to remove all columns in `unwantedHeaders`? If so, is it column index (Col A, Col C...) or contents (cells' content is `A`, `C` ...) in the header row?

Comment: The intended result should remove the columns listed leaving those not listed. While this works for the most part, it removes additional columns beyond what is defined.

Comment: Nearacle You withheld the loop start code from us. Did you try something like `For Each header In unwantedHeaders`? - please edit the missing code. Anyway the union solution proposed by @taller is less time consuming then executing iterative deletes :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Collect all columns with a range object
- Remove unwanted columns all at once
- Assuming the items in `unwantedHeaders` are column heading name

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm132112)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Delete method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144115)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.EntireColumn property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirecolumn?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144122)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub ModifyWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim vCol As Variant, delRng As Range
    Dim unwantedHeaders As Variant
    Dim insertColumn As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    unwantedHeaders = Array("A", "C", "G", "H", "K", "L", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "W", "AA", "AB", "AG", "AH", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BF", "BG", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BP", "BQ") ' Adjust with your headers
    For Each vCol In unwantedHeaders
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = ws.Cells(1, vCol)
        Else
            Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, ws.Cells(1, vCol))
        End If
    Next
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        delRng.EntireColumn.Delete
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

another method would be:

```
Sub ModifyWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim col As Range
    Dim unwantedHeaders As Variant
    Dim insertColumn As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    unwantedHeaders = Split("1-3-7-8-11-12-15-16-17-18-23-27-28-33-34-37-38-39-40-42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49-50-51-52-54-55-56-58-59-64-65-66-68-69", "-")
   
    With ws
        For i = UBound(unwantedHeaders) + 1 To LBound(unwantedHeaders) + 1 Step -1
            .Cells(Val(unwantedHeaders(i - 1))).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```